# In mysql use MAX function from other table

Tags: mysql

I wrote an example to describe my problem in a more complex database.
I use MySQL 5.7 with Delphi XE8.

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE customers 
(ID   INT         NOT NULL   AUTO_INCREMENT , 
Name VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL , 
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE orders
(IDorders    INT        NOT NULL   AUTO_INCREMENT ,
customerID   INT        NOT NULL , 
Description VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
DateOrder    Date       NOT NULL , 
PRIMARY KEY (IDorders),
INDEX DateOrderIndex (DateOrder, customerID) USING BTREE;
) ENGINE = InnoDB;


select *,
       (SELECT MAX(DateOrder) FROM Orders  WHERE Orders.customerID = 
customers.ID) as LastOrder
FROM customers
```

My problem is:
the customer table has 58,000 records
and
the orders table has 200,000 records
The query result occurs after 28 seconds.
Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need an index on `(customerID, DateOrder)` in `orders` table. But there is not even a column `Orders.customerID` in your CREATE statements.

Comment: For Paul Spiegel. Sorry, you're right.
I wrote an example to explain my problem, I forgot to write Orders.customerID.
Now, I do tests with indexes, maybe I can improve the times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `JOIN` with `MAX` and `GROUP BY` in subquery.

```
select c.*,
       t1.maxDt
FROM customers c 
JOIN (
    SELECT customerID,MAX(DateOrder) maxDt
    FROM Orders 
    GROUP BY customerID
) t1 on t1.customerID = c.ID
```

**Note**

if your query is slow you can try to create indexs on `Orders.customerID` and 
`customers.ID`

Comment: the order table has DateOrder index

Comment: I am trying your query in real (more complex) tables, it seems to be much faster, but the date of the last order is not right.
I do other tests with your code and let you know.

Comment: The query of (D-Shih) works, 2 seconds to get the result.
I put index in Orders on DateOrder, with phpmyadmin, is it correct or is there a different way to insert the index?

Comment: Perhaps the solution of (D-Shih) can be improved.
2 seconds to get the result.
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: By performing many tests, the query result is not good. If I add a client and run the query (select ...), the result occurs after 6 seconds.